# How can I access realm data saved on iPhone from Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, realm, apple-watch, ios-app-group

I saved some data with Realm on my iPhone, and in AppDelegate, I wrote

```
        var config = Realm.Configuration()
        let container = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.XXXXXXXX")
        let realmUrl = container!.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
        config.fileURL = realmUrl
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

Also, in ExtensionDelegate, I wrote the same.
But when I tried to access data from watch, it shows nothing.
I printed the URL and found that iPhone saves data in

> "Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/21B1330F-3B9D-4A45-9EE4-0D06F9A48866/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/3697965E-9A56-447E-B0EB-BC1722DB0BD0/default.realm"

But the watch saves in

> "Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B190D8C9-A6D8-4BE1-AD8D-7D2805BFA739/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/3E621FF7-86FA-4C49-9AC1-20C6C198CB2F/default.realm"

I'm now wondering how to access Realm data saved in my phone from my watch

**Now solved by transfering the whole realm file with WatchConnectivity**

Comment: You will have to look at watch connectivity to communicate between your phone and watch and get the data from the watch. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178664/how-to-send-data-from-iphone-to-apple-watch-in-os2-in-objective-c

Comment: @kapsym Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronizing Apple Watch and iPhone using Swift 3 and Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418523/synchronizing-apple-watch-and-iphone-using-swift-3-and-realm)

Comment: @DávidPásztor Seems really helpful，thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Realm Data with WatchOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644579/share-realm-data-with-watchos)